# Running Robot Files In A Thread (Dialog Box)

Tags: python, robotframework

I need to be able to run .robot files in a thread for a program I am writing but whenever there is a dialog box, the test automatically fails and says that

```
Dialogs library is not supported with timeouts on Python on this platform.
```

Does anyone know a possible solution to this, for a robot file with dialog boxes to be able to run in a thread? Robot files without dialog boxes run perfectly fine inside a thread.

```
import os
import threading
import robot

robot_test_object = []
for root, _, files in os.walk(str("C:/Users/Desktop/test")):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".robot"):
            robot_test_object.append(str(os.path.join(root, file)))
            print(robot_test_object)


def Run_Button():

    run_thread = threading.Thread(target=Run_Robot_Files)
    run_thread.daemon = True
    run_thread.start()

def Run_Robot_Files():
    for robot_tests in robot_test_object:
        robot.run(robot_tests)
```

Comment: See if this thread is useful..https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/641

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but it doesn't look like they came up with a solution.

Comment: Dialogs uses tkinter, and tkinter usually can't be run across threads. Though, you could probably implement your own dialog library that runs all of the dialogs in one thread, with the other threads communicating with it via a thread-safe queue.

Comment: Would you provide an example of how that would work please?